# Seal concrete crack

Tags: concrete, foundation, crack

My home is 60 years old and I am currently re-sealing my expansion joints with self-leveling sealant. This crack between the stairs (pier & beam foundation) and my walkway is  a vertical crack as opposed to horizontal, thus I don't think the self-leveling will work. I got some mortar repair quikrete mortar repair caulk as it would hold it's position, but on the can it says don't use on expansion joints. My thought is this gap acts as an expansion joint, is that correct? What would be the proper material to use? Thanks for the help.

[image: vertical separation]

Comment: you could try lifting the front of that slab ... lift where you were standing when you took the picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That gap isn't an expansion joint, and most residential concrete flatwork doesn't have expansion joints unless it's in a very long straight stretch. Most are simply crack control joints.

That's just a crack, and you can use almost any concrete repair product that stays flexible. Chances are it moves a bit seasonally.